# Indian CGPA to US GPA system

Tags: graduate-admissions, university, grading

I study in India and in here we have 10 pointer system. I wanted to convert my CGPA to american based GPA system of 4. I googled and got this [website](http://www.msinus.com/content/convert-cgpa-into-gpa-389/).

So does that mean I need only >8.5 to get a 4.

This may be a stupid question to some but please consider that I know nothing of american CGPA system.

Comment: There are so many variations within India that this question is rather moot.

Comment: The link in the version 1 (original version) did not break. So, I roll back to the original version. I don't know why the anonymous user tried to replace the working link. To the OP, if my edit contradicts to what you intend, please edit it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A US GPA is computed as an average of grades, mapped as follows:

- A = 4
- B = 3
- C = 2
- D = 1
- F = 0

In some universities, there are interpolations between these:

- A- = 3.67
- B+ = 3.33

and so on for B-, C+ and so on.

I've heard of an A+ being awarded a 4.33, but that's not the case in my university where A is the maximum grade.

At least in my recollection, this maps non-linearly to the Indian CGPA system which is

- A = 10
- B = 8
- C = 6
- D = 4

Because of the non-linearity, you can't just for e.g divide your score by 2.5. Moreover, there are statistical normalizations that complicate the process. Personally, if possible, I'd just list the CGPA as is. Your transcripts will reveal the grade specifics, and that's more useful than just the summary number. I wouldn't trust the link you provided since they don't appear to provide any rationale for the mapping.

Separately I'd have a hard time seeing an Indian CGPA of 8.6 and considering it a 4.0. Even with grade inflation, that would be over optimistic.

Comment: Indeed, don't attempt a conversion. U.S. admissions committees are well-accustomed to (trying to) interpret varying grading scales. Don't waste any time or energy in a misguided effort.